# How to get product after insert and update in query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get the same result as in Eloquent when create and update will return the model back.

In the case of query builder, how can I return the model when insert returns boolean and update returns the ID of the updated row?!?!?

For example: `DB::table('users')->insert( ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0] );`

Will return boolean, instead what I am looking for is to get that created user, same behavior with `User::create()`.

`DB::table('users')->update()` will return the ID of the updated row, again I want the updated row as an object same behavior with `User::update()`.

I know that `insertGetId()` will give me the ID when I use `insert()`, but I don't want to make an extra step to use the ID and find the row.

Also, for the update, I don't want to use the ID that `update()` returns to use it in order to find the row.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Please more specify. Give some example, codes etc.

Comment: @whoknows check this https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-in-laravel-57

Answer (score 2):

Use `insertGetId()` instead of `insert()` and then `find()` the model. For example:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(['name' => 'Ivanka', 'email' => 'ivanka@ivanka.com']); 
$user = User::find($id);
```

When you are updating you have the `id`, so just `find()` it: `User::find($id)`.

Documentation that explains how `insertGetId()` works: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts

Comment: I'm not looking for this.

DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);

The code above will return boolean. Instead what I am looking for is to retrieve that created user, same behavior such as User::create().

Comment: If you want to retrieve the model, use the ORM or use the approach I suggested. You can't (and you should not) make the query builder act as the Eloquent ORM, because both have different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use from below code if you want.

find the last insert column:

```
$last_id = Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

and next:

```
$user = User::find($last_id);
```